# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: al pasar un parametro x url

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular

Buenas tardes Estimados,

Tengo problema con capturar un parámetro mediante la URL de la siguiente manera
Versión de Angular 10.

Soy nuevo con angular y estoy siguiendo un curso, pero cuando realizo la aplicación como explican creando el `app.routing.ts`, me da error con algunos componentes me imagino que es por la versión, pero al hacerlo de esta forma si compila hasta pasar el parámetro por URL da un error

App.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {  VideojuegoComponent } from './videojuego/videojuego.component';
import {  RolesVideoJuegoComponent } from './rolesVideoJuego/rolesvideojuego.component';
import { CursosComponent } from './cursos/cursos.component';
import { ZapatillasComponent } from './zapatillas/zapatillas.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';


const Rutas:Routes=[

  {
    path:'',
    pathMatch:'full',
    redirectTo:'app-home'
  },
  {
    path:'app-home',
    component:HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'profile/',
    component:ProfileComponent
  },
  {
    path:'profile/:nombreC/',
    component:ProfileComponent
  },
  {
    path:'dashboard',
    component:DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path:'zapatillas',
    component:ZapatillasComponent
  },
  {
    path:'videojuego',
    component:VideojuegoComponent
  },
  {
    path:'rolesvideojuego',
    component:RolesVideoJuegoComponent
    /*, CUANDO QUIERA ANIDAR O TENER UN LINK HIJO DENTRO DE UNO PADRE
    children:[
      {
        path:'',
        pathMatch:'prefix',
        redirectTo:'RolesVideoJuegoComponent (HIJO)'
      }
      {
        path:RolesVideoJuegoComponent (HIJO),
        component:RolesVideoJuegoComponent (HIJO),
      }
    ]*/
  },
  {
    path:'cursos',
    component:CursosComponent
  },
  {
    path:'cursos:/nombre',
    component:CursosComponent
  },
  {
    path: '404', 
    component:HomeComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    VideojuegoComponent,
    RolesVideoJuegoComponent,
    CursosComponent,
    ZapatillasComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(Rutas, {
      enableTracing:true
    })
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

cursosComponent.ts

````
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cursos',
  templateUrl: './cursos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cursos.component.css']
})
export class CursosComponent implements OnInit {
  public nombreC:string;


  constructor(
    private _route:ActivatedRoute,
    private _router:Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._route.params.subscribe((params:Params) =>{
      this.nombreC = params.nombreC;
      
      //this.nombre = params['nombre'];
        console.log(this.nombreC);

    });
  }```

cursos.component.html
<br>
<h1> MODULO DE CURSO </h1>
<h3 *ngIf="nombreC">Bienvenido al curso de  {{nombre}} </h3>

----------


<br>
````

Me da este error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cursos/andres'
> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cursos/andres'

El parámetro que se esta pasando por la `URL` es `"andres"`

¿Alguien puede indicarme cual es el error en mi código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes un error aqui:

```
    //En esta parte
    path:'cursos:/nombre',
    component:CursosComponent
  },
```

Tiene que ser `path: 'cursos/:nombre'`

De otra manera tu route para que haga match deberia ser `http://tuApp.com/cursos:/nombre` literalmente.